# Select query with primary key group by in sub query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to select the records from my table. My table contains nearly 20 columns and more than 500 000 records.For example:

My Sample table Data:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

The Column C1 is the primary key of the table. I have used the following query

```
SELECT  ( SELECT    FIRST(C1)
          FROM      TableName AS F
          WHERE     F.C2 = TableName.C2
        ) AS Exp1 ,
        TableName.C2 ,
        TableName.C3 ,
        TableName.C4
FROM    TableName
```

It returns the Desired result which I expected, But it takes more time to return the result. Is there any way to speed my query?. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired result is the same image.

Comment: @Ola Ekdahl In Desired result the column C1 results changed for next rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the result from your previous query - returning Min(C1) and grouped by C2, C3, and C4 - to a temp table.

Then join your main table to the temp table on C2, C3, C4 and select Min(C1) from the temp table and ignore C1 from the main table.